# How to repair text selection in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm

I mean because, for example, normally this looks like that:

[image: normal look]

but when I select text and deselect it,

[image: broken look]

I can't write, to repair this I must press 'insert' key on keyboard, or type some text.
When I select the text, I can't delete it by pressing 'backspace' or replace it by just typing text.
How I can repair this? I want to it works as in any normal text editor.

Comment: Do you have the vim plugin? Potentially similar issue on a different JetBrains IDE: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009380319-My-cursor-is-converted-to-Insert-Mode-by-itself-if-i-highlight-anything

Answer (score 0):

Try This for Toggle Sticky Selection

> **Windows: Ctrl + Shift + A**

> **MAC : CMD + Shift + A**

Hope it Gonna Work